# Best way to check if a collection only contains elements in another collection?

Tags: python

What is the best way to check if an array/tuple/list only contains elements in another array/tuple/list?

I tried the following 2 approaches, which is better/more pythonic for the different kinds of collections?
What other (better) methods can I use for this check?

```
import numpy as np

input = np.array([0, 1, -1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1])
bits = np.array([0, 1, -1])

# Using numpy
a=np.concatenate([np.where(input==bit)[0] for bit in bits])
if len(a)==len(input):
    print 'Valid input'

# Using sets
if not set(input)-set(bits):
    print 'Valid input'
```

Comment: I would say the set method is a very straightforward way to do this. Is there any reason you would need something different from that approach?

Comment: The set looks much cleaner, but is it also more optimal for all the different kinds of collections/ large collections?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `# Using numpy` one is awfully inefficient for large sets in that it creates an entire copy of your input list.

I'd probably do:

```
if all(i in bits for i in input):
    print 'Valid input'
```

That's an *extremely* pythonic way to write what you're trying to do, and it has the benefit that it won't create an entire `list` (or `set`) that might be large, and it'll stop (and return `False`) the first time it encounters an element from `input` that's not in `bits`.

Comment: Good points about the extra-copying and exiting on the first false condition. Also, I think your method works just as well for different kinds of collections

Comment: [numpy.in1d](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.in1d.html#numpy.in1d) is even more efficient

Answer (score 5):

Since you're already using numpy arrays, you can use the [in1d](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.in1d.html#numpy.in1d) function:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> 
>>> input = np.array([0, 1, -1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1])
>>> bits = np.array([0, 1, -1])
>>> 
>>> if np.in1d(input, bits).all():
...     print 'Valid input'
... 
Valid input
```

Comment: in1d is indeed better for numpy arrays, and according to the docs is _roughly equivalent to `np.array([item in b for item in a])`_. Since this is exactly @sblom's answer and his is more generic in that it works also for tuples, lists, etc. he gets the accept

Answer (score 2):

Generally you would just use set this way, it could be faster than recalculating a new set using operator -:

```
input = set([0, 1, -1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1])
bits = set([0, 1, -1])

input.issubset(bits)
```

EDIT:

issubset is a method written for exactly this problem (see source at http://hg.python.org/releasing/2.7.3/file/7bb96963d067/Objects/setobject.c). It basically is an equivalent for:

```
def issubset(self, other):
    if len(self) > len(other):
        return False

    for i in self:
        if i not in other:
            return False

    return True
```

Comment: Good point about recalculating the set. Do you have any idea about how efficient this function is for large sets?

Comment: I do not know exactly, all depends on the inner workings of a Python set, but I think this should be in O(n); also, notice that issubset can bail out on INVALID input as soon as it finds an element not in bits.